# Cannot read property 'props' of null with mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, properties, null, redux, native

Hi i am getting in to react native with redux and redux saga and currently i need to load cities array to a picker via ajax called and this is my code so far.

inside render method :

```
render() { 
if (this.props.loaded) {
  // 
}

return (
  <ContainerScroll>
    <StatusBar translucent={false} barStyle="light-content" />
    <Section style={{ height: deviceHeightOneThird }}>
      <LabelScreenHeader text={I18n.t('signupEmailHeaderLabel')} />
    </Section>

    <Section>
      <TextInputDefault
        label={I18n.t('signupEmailInputLabel')}
        keyboardType="email-address"
        onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
        value={this.state.email}
        placeholder={I18n.t('signupEmailInputPlaceHolder')}
      />
      <TextInputDefault
        label={I18n.t('signupPhoneNumberInputLabel')}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        onChangeText={phoneNumber => this.setState({ phoneNumber })}
        value={this.state.phoneNumber}
        placeholder={I18n.t('signupPhoneNumberInputPlaceHolder')}
      />
      <TextInputDefault
        label={I18n.t('signupNameInputLabel')}
        keyboardType="default"
        onChangeText={name => this.setState({ name })}
        value={this.state.name}
        placeholder={I18n.t('signupNameInputPlaceHolder')}
      />
      <TextInputDefault
        label={I18n.t('signupPasswordInputLabel')}
        keyboardType="default"
        onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
        value={this.state.password}
        secureTextEntry
        placeholder={I18n.t('signupPasswordInputPlaceHolder')}
      />
      <PickerDefault
        iosHeader={I18n.t('signupCityDropdownDefaultValue')}
        selectedValue={this.state.cityPickerValue}
        onValueChange={city => this.setState({ cityPickerValue: city })}
      >
        {console.log('this.props ---- ', this.props.cities) /* this is where error pop up when calling cities*/}
        <Picker.Item label={I18n.t('signupCityDropdownDefaultValue')} value="default" />

        {this.displayCities}
      </PickerDefault>

      <Button
        buttonText={I18n.t('signupEmailButtonText')}
        onPress={this.handleSignUp}
        wrapperStyleProp={{
          marginTop: 30,
        }}
      />
    </Section>
  </ContainerScroll>
);
}
```

this is mapstatetoprops method with connect :

```
// here in mapstatetoprops method all cities are fetched successfully
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  cities: state.commonDataReducer.cities,
  loaded: state.commonDataReducer.loaded,
});

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignupEmail);
```

error coming when i call this.props in jsx tags . as an example , this line

```
 {console.log('this.props ---- ', this.props.cities)
```

im kinda self studying react native with redux and redux saga. so bear with me if this is a newbie thing.

thanks all

Comment: How are you creating your component? Include it in your question. `class Blah extends Component` or `React.createClass()`?

Comment: please post your error and the reducer as well. :)

Comment: Please post full component. Also you can console log inside `mapStateToProps` and see if `state.commonDataReducer.cities` is set.